# GCP Alert email customization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add more text to 'alert' email that Google send when something happens in cloud. For example I build an log based alert and when some threshhold reached then 'alert' email send. I read multiple time the document:  [Using Markdown and variables in documentation templates](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables) but whatever I put into 'Documentation' field come as simple text - without actual `value` of the field :( For example I receive an email with:

```
Error Text: ${log.extracted_label.rawLogIndex}
```

For example I have a log entry like this:

[image]

I want the **value** of `labels\error_stack` to be send in alert email - how I can do that ? Could you add an example ?

Answer (score -1):

You can include the log data using the **variables** in the `document` section of the alert policy. For this [log-based](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/monitoring-logs#lba) alert needs to be created.

**To answer your question**: In order to use the variable in documentation, you need to create a label for your logs. You can create a label using extractor expressions. These expressions will notify the cloud logging to extract the label's value from the logs you defined.

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels#overview) will help to understand the labels for log-based metrics along with example. You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RgJjx4IxMs) to create a log-based alerts.